# JavaScript loading twice in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I add the JavaScript library to the Rails asset folder and have it configured in my erb file using: <%= javascript_include_tag('scripts.js') %>, the HTML code with the classes associated with the JavaScript file load twice.

I have attached an example [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fO0XM.jpg). When I link the JavaScript files to the public folder this issue does not happen, but instead the JavaScript does not show up.

JavaScript

```
$(function() {
    $("a.page-scroll").bind("click", function(a) {
        var b = $(this);
        $("html, body").stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $(b.attr("href")).offset().top
         }, 1500, "easeInOutExpo"), a.preventDefault()
    })
})
```

Html.erb

```
<li>
    <a class="page-scroll" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a class="page-scroll" href="#me">About Me</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a>
</li>
```

There are no relevant console errors.

Note: This works perfectly fine without Rails.

Comment: It is irrelevant to post a [question twice](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34388869/2945616).

Comment: as you use `javascript_include_tag(js_file)` and in `application.js` you also use `#// require_tree`  as `require_tree .` call only loads the tree for the /app/assets/javascripts/ directory so load it multiple times